# Why isn't the magrittr %<>% assignment pipe working with R's native pipe (|>)

Tags: r, magrittr

I've noticed that search-replace `%>%` with `|>` does induce some errors. The obvious one is the lack of a place-holder, i.e.

```
mtcars %>%
  lm(mpg ~ hp, data = .)
```

has to be rewritten into:

```
mtcars |> 
  (\(d) lm(mpg ~ hp, data = d))()
```

another thing that appears is that `%<>%` suddenly fails to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the assignment pipe, `%<>%` is no longer is due [operator precedence](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Syntax.html). The `%<>%` occurs before the `|>`, see below eacmple:

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

a <- tibble(a = 1:3)
a %<>% 
   mutate(b = a * 2) |> 
   mutate(c = a * 3) |> 
   filter(a <= 2)
a
```

Returns

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      a     b
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     2     4
3     3     6
```

Thus the

```
a %<>% 
  mutate(b = a * 2)
```

Is the only section that was saved. You can also get a feeling that this may be the case as you get the intended table printed instead which should never be the case with a tibble assignment.

Answer (score 4):

As of [R 4.2.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html), with the forward pipe, you can now use the underscore placeholder (counterpart to magrittr's dot) to pipe object to a selected, named argument:

> In a forward pipe |> expression it is now possible to use a named argument with the placeholder _ in the rhs call to specify where the lhs is to be inserted. The placeholder can only appear once on the rhs.

```r
mtcars |> 
  lm(mpg ~ hp, data = _)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           hp  
   30.09886     -0.06823
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw that they were planning it in the beginning but thought they dropped it. It should make the code much more readable than the ugly anonymous function solution